# iframe element displays video fine on windows browsers, but doesnt appear for IOS

Tags: iframe, youtube

Asking this to share my solution, because I searched for way too long to find this work around and not have it be a simple answer...

So: I have a youtube video embedded on my site. And it works perfectly fine on my windows machine (Google Chrome, Edge, Firefox, all tested and working). Yet, when I tested it on my iPhone chrome browser it displayed nothing and made the entire page link back to the homepage. The iframe provided was:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And, like I said, was displaying fine on Windows machines. I had a colleague use the web inspector on his mac to see if the code wasn't loading or something of the sort, but no dice. Code appeared exactly the same in both browsers, and gave no errors (no cross site error, even).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I arrived at this (extremely simple) solution from EncodeDNA (https://www.encodedna.com/html5/embed-youtube-video-in-a-webpage-without-iframe.htm). Just use an object instead of an iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Embed YouTube Video without iFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
    <object data='https://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id?autoplay=1' 
        width='560px' height='315px'>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

I plugged it in and it worked on all browsers, including (and most importantly in this case) IOS browsers.